# Java Deployment Toolkit

Tags: javascript, web, applet, java-deployment-toolkit

I have one applet program and one javascript program.  I have tried to send data (say xyz) from applet to javascript. The javascript contains 2 line of applet code. The problem is that , when I try to run the html file, every time browser says 
" This plugin has security vulnarability , Activate Java Deployment Toolkit ".
I have the the java security level at lowest level and  "java (TM) platform" is always active.

I don't what to do , it has stucked me. I cann't move forward....plz guide me and good some really good solution for this...THank you

Comment: *"some really good solution for this"*  Don't *use **applets!***  If you are forced to use them, charge double and get prepared for pain..

Comment: 1) Did you click on "activate java deployment toolkit" (in the plugins settings of your browser you can activate it)? Usually it works after that. 2) We need some more information - what java version are you using? Did you sign your applet with an official certificate? (Since recently this is mandatory!)

Comment: @ Andrw Thompson...It seems like as you said but I can't figure out how to do it..I have to send data from java application to javascript ...any good suggestion for it..

Comment: @ Lonzak  , i Use JDK 1.7.0_45/jre 7 in Netbean for 64 bit of my computer and to display applet i have used same version of java of 32 bit (..coz mozilla firefox is 32 bit.) 
and what is this, ""did i sign my aplet with an official certificate "...??